# Angular 2 > Compodoc > Serving /docs on Github Pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am using compodoc to generate docs for my Angular project.

Right now, I am generating the docs manually (in my local) before pushing the repo to Github. The /docs folder gets served by github pages. Including the docs files to the commits make the commits confusingly big. It would be very nice if the compodoc script could have been executed in github and the docs folder generated there.

I know Github is not a place to build code but as far as I am aware, you can generate this kind of a workflow with Jeykll. Has anyone ever solved a problem like this?

Answer (score 5):

I am the core maintainer of Compodoc.

Please have a look at the demo repository : https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc-demo-todomvc-angular

It is a great example of how you can serve the generated documentation. There is a travis task for it. Look the travis.yml file.

It runs first the npm doc task that runs compodoc. After it launch the deploy script.

`- npm run doc
 - bash ./deploy.sh`

In this deploy script, i just move into documentation folder, and commit everything on the gh-pages branch.

`cd documentation
git add . && \
git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages" && \
git push --force "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" master:gh-pages > /dev/null 2>&1`

Regards

Comment: I'm having a tough time with as well with serving docs to gh-pages. Thanks for posting that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in my Jenkins job by doing:

```
git add docs && git commit -m "my commit message"  
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix docs master`:gh-pages --force
```

I found the answer in the comments [here](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490)